# Let $R$ be an Euclidean domain. Let $p$ be irreducible. Let $a\ge1$. Show that every non-zero submodule of $R/Rp^a$ contains $Rp^{a-1}/Rp^a.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals

> Let $R$ be a Euclidean domain. Let $p$ be irreducible. Let $a\geq 1$. Show that every non-zero submodule of $R/Rp^a$ contains $Rp^{a-1}/Rp^a$.

I bet the answer is stupidly obvious, but I just can't see it. So do I just consider a non-trivial submodule of $R/Rp^a$. It has a non-zero element (say) $u+Rp^a$. Where do I go from here? Do I use the division algorithm? What's $p$ being irreducible or $a\gneq 1$ got to do with it?

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Isn't "contains" correct here?  After all $R \supset R p^{a-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $K$ be a non-zero submodule of $R/Rp^a$. $K$ is of the form $I/Rp^a$ with $I$ a submodule of $R$ (that is, an ideal of $R$) with $I\supseteq Rp^a$. Since $R$ is euclidean (in fact it's enough to be a PID) we have $I=Rr$ for some $r\in R$. The inclusion $Rr\supseteq Rp^a$ shows that $r\mid p^a$, so $r=p^b$ with $0\le b\le a$. If $b=a$ then $I=Rp^a$ and therefore $K=0$, a contradiction. Thus $b\le a-1$ and $$K=I/Rp^a=Rp^b/Rp^a\supseteq Rp^{a-1}/Rp^a.$$